# What does this sentence translate to or what does 見ていて and 様子 mean in this context?

Tags: translation, words, て-form

Here's the line from NHK easy news:

> ザギトワ選手のインスタグラムは世界で４５万人ぐらいの人が**見ていて**、犬をかわいがる**様子**が人気になっています。

[Link](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011455241000/k10011455241000.html) to the news article.

Separating the part before and after comma into two parts,

> ザギトワ選手のインスタグラムは世界で４５万人ぐらいの人が**見ていて、**

What does 見ていて mean here ? My translation is "Zagitova's instagram account is being followed by 450k people" but I am not sure if follow is the correct translation of 見ていて.

> 犬をかわいがる**様子**が人気になっています

"The condition of dog being cute is getting popular" doesn't make a lot of sense to me. The confusion here arises mostly because of 様子.

> 犬をかわいがる**様子**が人気になっています。

What would be a good English translation for the entire sentence or what do 見ていて and 様子 translate to in this context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`見ていて` -> `見ている` -> `見る` ( look/see )

The subject of `見ていて` is the preceding `４５万人ぐらいの人` (around 450k people)

So, more literally it's "In regards to Zagitova's Instagram, around 450k people (in the world) are looking [at it]", but "follow" can be used too.
The `-て` form is used to connect the two sentences.

For the second part, `犬をかわいがる` does not mean "dog is being cute", but "[Zagitova] is playing with/showing affection to the dog" (see [かわいがる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/srch/all/%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%81%84%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B/m0u/)). Note how `を` is marking the object of the verb.

Next, `様子` can mean "condition" but in the sense of "appearance/look [usually of someone]". A better meaning in this context is probably "state; state of affairs; situation; circumstances". I.e. it's the scenes/situation of Zagitova petting the dog which makes her Instagram popular.